# Replace words starting with a backslash in Python

Tags: python, regex, backslash

I need to remove words starting with a backslash from a string. I have tried the following (and slight variations) but the words are not removed.

```
test = "(students \u2019 education, 1, 3) || (DCUCampaign 8, 2, 2) || (Projects Stories, 1, 2) || (DCU, 14, 1) || (\u201c DCU graduate \u201d, 1, 4)"
```

Here is the regex I've tried:

```
re.sub(r"\b\\\w+", "", str(test))
```

Comment: The string "\u2019" does not start with a backslash.

Comment: There are no backslashes in your test string. "\uXXXX" is an escaped character representing the unicode as hexadecimal.

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: So maybe you rephrase your question by applying the feedback from the comments ot your task "need to remove ]some] words [...] from a string" and I am sure people will provide solutions. As is unchanged it is a broken or to broad question (IMO).

Comment: Actually, a non-word boundary must be used here if you plan to match ``\`` only after a non-word char: `r"\B\\\w+"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
re.sub(r"\\\w+", "", str(test))
```

You don't need word boundary `\b`, just a backslash and word characters.
A word boundary `\b` is a virtual character between non-word characters and a word characters, because example of non-word characters: space, backslash and few others. So what you were doing is checking that a word starts and that the word begins with a backslash, which is mutually exclusive.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation with your code? Just dropping code doesn't help (especially not when it doesn't work; at least it doesn't for me).

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra It works, I just double checked, it removes the unicode escapes

Comment: Can you please tell me why the use of word boundary doesn't work?

Comment: a word boundary is a *virtual* character between a non-word character and a word character, `\` is not a word character so doing \b\\\w won't work

Comment: This actually worded for me. Thanks

Comment: @krzyk, found the difference. This wasn't working for me on python 3.4. Python 2 seems to accept your way of working.

Comment: @Markus: This will find ``\word`` even in `text\word`, while `r"\B\\\w+"` won't. Please check your requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I thought this and checked but shouldn't make a difference. Having said that, your solution with a capital 'B' works so I've implemented it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `\u2019` is actually not `\u2019` but rather the [`Right Single Quotation Mark`](http://unicode-table.com/en/2019/): ’

It is encoded in [`unicode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and is just one character.

Another example:

This is the newline character: `\n` In your code this will not print `\n` but rather a new line (like pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

To remove all unicode values that are not in the ascii caracter space (0 to 127) use the following code:

```
text = "".join([i if ord(i) < 128 else "" for i in text])
```

Or if you want to replace them with a whitespace `" "`:

```
text = "".join([i if ord(i) < 128 else " " for i in text])
```

You could also use a regex like the following:

```
re.sub(r"[^\x00-\x7F]+", " ", text)
```

Note: `\x7F` is 127 in hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks Simon - The encoding domain is still a huge mine field to me (and assume others).

Answer (score 1):

Since the `\` is a non-word character, to prevent matching `\word` in `text\word`, you need to use a `\B` - *a non-word boundary* that matches at the places where `\b` does not match.

In short: `\B` matches at the start of the string before a non-word char, or at the end of the string after a non-word char, or between the characters of the same type (i.e. between `bb`, `b1`, `b_`, `,.`, etc.).

See more explanation [here, *Not-a-word-boundary: `\B`* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#notb).

Use

```
re.sub(r"\B\\\w+", "", str(test))
         ^^
```

If you need to make the non-word boundary Unicode aware, do not forget to pass the `flags=UNICODE`.

Answer (score 0):

As more people have pointed out in the comments is that `\u2019` is actually an unicode escape sequence, which will be expanded to `’`. This feature is only in Python 3+, You can replace that with: `r'\u2019'`. Or in Python 2 with `u'\u2019'`.

But you will soon notice that only replaces that one character, if you however want to replace all non ascii characters use the following regex:

```
r'[^\x00-\x7F]+'
```